TypeError: `__init__()` takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
1. I'm encountering an error while trying to create a parser for 'c'. The error message is as follows:
Error creating parser for 'c': __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given). Traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Thes_Dev\SourceParser\scripts\parse_functions.py", line 129, in get_parser
    language = Language(lib_path, language_name)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Details:

Error Message: TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
File: Since it is open source you can see for more context https://github.com/TgGeda/source_parser/tree/main/parse_functions.py
Line: 129
Code Snippet:
language = Language(lib_path, language_name)



Context:
I'm trying to initialize a Language object with lib_path and language_name as arguments. However, it seems like the __init__ method of the Language class is only expecting one argument.
Question:
How can I resolve this error? Is there a mistake in how I'm passing the arguments to the Language class, or do I need to modify the __init__ method of the Language class to accept two arguments?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

You will need to show your code. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. Questions must be self-contained, your source code must be here, not there.

The readme for tree-sitter-py says to do
import tree_sitter_python as tspython
from tree_sitter import Language, Parser
PY_LANGUAGE = Language(tspython.language())
parser = Parser(PY_LANGUAGE)

so  that does indicate tree_sitter.Language() accepts only one parameter, and you're now passing it two, hence the error.

Thank you! @Akk. But all options failed .  My intention is to parse large corpus of source code dataset in my local machine. The source code is multilingual implementations which makes difficult to handle all scenarios using   https://github.com/tree-sitter/py-tree-sitter?tab=readme-ov-file#install-languages because it is primarily focus on python implementation.

The tree-sitter library, the constructor generally needs a language name along with the compiled library path but I got C_LANGUAGE = Language('F:\Thes_Dev\SourceParser\parsers\build\c.dll', 'c')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: init() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given).
When I remove  name i have got C_LANGUAGE = Language('F:\Thes_Dev\SourceParser\parsers\build\c.dll')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: an integer is required

The Readme is using the precompiled Python language module as an example. You can find the precompiled modules for other languages on PyPI too, eg https://pypi.org/project/tree-sitter-rust/
